# How to write a code inside <pre> tag without apply the code

Tags: javascript, html

I have two places, the first is,`<textarea></textarea>` and used to write the code.
The second is, `<pre></pre>` and used to display the code.
The problem is, when write a code in the text area to display it in the second place, the code is applied and displayed as HTML element not just code as I want.

**The wrong behavior:**

[image]

**The correct behavior (What I want):**

[image]

**The code:**

```
<textarea id="inputCode" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
<pre id="outputCode"></pre>
```

Comment: Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/h175y2vx/

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) to set the value of the second textarea will add the textual value only, not the HTML.

```
<pre id="code"></pre>

document.getElementById("code").innerText = "<input type='text' />";
```

Will insert in to the `pre` tags,

```
<input type='text' />
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h238288/)

Comment: I don't mind down-votes but please do tell me what I did wrong to deserve said down-vote.