# How to Ignore HTML Tags when Using document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of Javascript code that is supposed to show the line

```
document.write(\" <textarea name=\"Text1\" cols=\"+col+\"rows=\"+row+\" id=\"textbox\" style=\"HelveticaNeue-Light\">\");
```

This is done by using `document.write`. So it is basically

```
document.write("document.write(\" <textarea name=\"Text1\" cols=\"+col+\"rows=\"+row+\" id=\"textbox\" style=\"HelveticaNeue-Light\">\");");
```

Firstly, I pass the above string to an array, and then later on in the program display it using `document.write`.

The problem is that when display it, it actually makes a text box and shows it. I believe this is happening because HTML just goes through and checks for tags, regardless of their position in quotes, etc.

How do I fix this? I just want to display the actual line, not the output from the line. Is there anyway to do this? Can I use something different than `document.write`? Can I output it to a text box that simply display it? Is that enough?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.write` at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a code inside <pre> tag without apply the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868341/how-to-write-a-code-inside-pre-tag-without-apply-the-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the tags. These symbols: `<` `>` must be encoded as `&lt;` `&gt;`.

Your example should be similar to this:

```
document.write(" `&lt;textarea name=\"Text1\" cols=\"+col+\"rows=\"+row+\" id=\"textbox\" style=\"HelveticaNeue-Light\"&gt;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

**Try this :**

```js
document.write("document.write(\" &lt;textarea name='Text1' cols=\"+col+\" rows=\"+row+\" id='textbox' style='HelveticaNeue-Light'&gt;\");");
```

Comment: This won't work. The output is **NOT** a valid `javascript` statement. **Text1** , **textbox** and **HelveticaNeue-Light** should be enclosed in `'` (single-quotes)

Comment: Or the `"` (double-quotes)  must be escaped

Answer (score 0):

You can add your string directly to an element by setting its `innerText`:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.innerText = '<p>These p tags will be displayed as text</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You to HTML encode it, like so

```
document.write("document.write(\" <textarea name=\"Text1\" cols=\"+col+\"rows=\"+row+\" id=\"textbox\" style=\"HelveticaNeue-Light\">\");".replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'));
```